# AngularJS bind TList<string> to <select>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have TList type object to return and to bind with . Data which i am receiving is,

Groups: Array[4]
   0: "Administrators"
   1: "Guests"
   2: "Users"
   3: "HR"
   4: "Developers"

Can anyone tell me how i can bind Groups to ?

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat was helpful. I was missing ng-repeat to use in correct way